# How to avoid the function calls depth limit?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I would like to know if it's possible to avoid the functions call depth limit of Firestore security rules for my following code.

What's counted as function? Just my own created or also something like `size()`?

```
  function isValidItem(data, item) {
    return 
        ( // Person
          data.items[item].keys().hasAll(['image','type','name','job','age','party','experience'])
          && data.items[item].image.size() >= 1 && data.items[item].image.size() <= 200
          && data.items[item].type.size() >= 5 && data.items[item].type.size() <= 10
          && data.items[item].name.size() >= 1 && data.items[item].name.size() <= 50
          && data.items[item].job.size() >= 1 && data.items[item].job.size() <= 50
          && data.items[item].party.size() >= 1 && data.items[item].party.size() <= 50
          && data.items[item].experience.size() >= 1 && data.items[item].experience.size() <= 50
          && data.items[item].age.matches('^[0-9]+$')
        )
        || 
        ( // Party
            data.items[item].keys().hasAll(['image','type','name','orientation','experience','promi'])
          && data.items[item].image.size() >= 1 && data.items[item].image.size() <= 200
          && data.items[item].type.size() >= 5 && data.items[item].type.size() <= 10
          && data.items[item].name.size() >= 1 && data.items[item].name.size() <= 50
          && data.items[item].orientation.size() >= 1 && data.items[item].orientation.size() <= 50
          && data.items[item].experience.size() >= 1 && data.items[item].experience.size() <= 50
          && data.items[item].promi.size() >= 1 && data.items[item].promi.size() <= 50
        );
  }

  function itemsAreValid(data) {
    return data.items.size() >= 1
        && data.items.size() <= 10
        && isValidItem(data, 0)
        && (data.items.size() < 2 || isValidItem(data, 1))
        && (data.items.size() < 3 || isValidItem(data, 2))
        && (data.items.size() < 4 || isValidItem(data, 3))
        && (data.items.size() < 5 || isValidItem(data, 4))
        && (data.items.size() < 6 || isValidItem(data, 5))
        && (data.items.size() < 7 || isValidItem(data, 6))
        && (data.items.size() < 8 || isValidItem(data, 7))
        && (data.items.size() < 9 || isValidItem(data, 8))
        && (data.items.size() < 10 || isValidItem(data, 9));
  }

  function isValidTitle(data) {
    return data.title.size() >= 1 
        && data.title.size() <= 200
  }

  function isAuthed() {
    return request.auth.uid != null
        && request.auth.token.email_verified == true;
  }

  allow create, update:
    if isAuthed()
    && request.resource.data.user == request.auth.uid
    && request.resource.data.status == "review"
    && isValidTitle(request.resource.data)
    && itemsAreValid(request.resource.data);
```

Comment: The function call depth limit has to do with recursive functions.  That is to say, functions that call themselves, or call other functions that call themselves.  I don't see any recursive functions here.  Can you show the **complete and minimal** set of rules that causes the problem?  What is data()?

Comment: Then I've misunderstood this call depth stuff. Thanks for the explanation. I've edited my questions code. Unfortunately it's still not working.

Comment: I still don't see a recursive function here, but you're still not showing a complete example.  isAuthed() and isValidTitle() are missing.  Have you tried paring down the rules to something minimal, then incrementally making them more complex in order to figure out what the exact problem is?

Comment: I think, I just named my problem wrong - it has nothing to do with call depth. I've added the two missing functions. When I remove the last 7 rows of `itemsAreValid(data)` the rules are working. One more line and it fails.

Comment: So, what exactly is the text of the error?

Comment: Where can I see or log why it exactly fails? I just get consoled that there are insufficient permissions.

(correction: not the last 7 rows, the 4 rows.)

Comment: There's no log, sorry. Are you able to test in the console simulator?  Are you able to test with the emulator for node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked this out with the Firebase security rules team, and we found that the limit you're exceeding here is almost certainly the total number of expressions allowed.  This is documented to be 10,000 right now, but that number is actually incorrect.  It should be documented as 1,000.  That's why, when you pared down the rules some, it was able to start worked.  You likely came in under the 1000 limit at that point.

What you can do to improve your situation is stop calling functions repeatedly unnecessarily.  For example, instead of `isValidItem(map, key)` and then calling `map[key]` repeatedly, you could just write `isValidItem(value)`

Unfortunately, there is currently no log or debugging available for security rules, so you'll need to take a guess sometimes when things go wrong.

We're going to fix the documentation, and also discuss more internally.

Comment: Ah, ok,  thanks a lot for your help! At least we discovered the problem... With your advice It's now working for 7 instead of 10 items - that should also be enough for me.

Please also discuss an improvement for the simulator. Creating larger testable documents is a pain. And better log functionality would be awesome as well! :-)

Comment: How are these expressions counted? I don't see how the number of expressions would add up to anywhere near to a 1000 in the code provided.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson would you be able to explain how are Fabian's rules amount to 1000 expressions? How are these expression counted? I think I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Calling data() -> document reference every time.**

The limit is document access, in this calling data() is the problem. You are referring document by calling data many time. To avoid this, you can pass data() into function and validate everything inside it.

```
Access call limits
There is a limit on document access calls per rule set evaluation:

10 for single-document requests and query requests.
20 for multi-document reads, transactions, and batched writes. The previous limit of 10 also applies to each operation.

For example, imagine you create a batched write request with 3 write operations and that your security rules use 2 document access calls to validate each write. In this case, each write uses 2 of its 10 access calls and the batched write request uses 6 of its 20 access calls.

Exceeding either limit results in a permission denied error. Some document access calls may be cached, and cached calls do not count towards the limits
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions

Comment: I think and hope, I've done what you said, but unfortunately it's still not working. :-( (see my edited question)